# Plot scatter graph using matplotlib with three different values

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to create a scatter graph of following data

```
dict_a["src_ip"] =  This contains range of source IP all unique (192.168.x.x)
dict_a["src_port"] =  This contains range of source port all unique (1..100)
dict_a["time"] = This contains range of epoch time
```

I want to plot a graph with X axis having `time`, y axis having `port` and then plot the src_ip dots on the graph which will show that particular IP came tried connecting on this port on this time

I used something like this

```
plt.scatter(x=pkt_data['time'], y=pkt_data['src_port'])
```

Not sure how can i plot graph for the required information

I tried adding new code as below

```
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
    ax.scatter(time, port, alpha=0.8, c=z, edgecolors='none', s=30, label=ip)
    print(tuple(ip))
    plt.title('Matplot scatter plot')
    plt.legend(loc=5)
    plt.show()
```

I am getting graph as below
[image]

Only problem is with the legend now. the color marker is coming in single line for all the IP's. Can i get this for every diff ip. `z` is just random number

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Color by Column Values in Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14885895/color-by-column-values-in-matplotlib)

Comment: @Anwarvic: Unfortunately that does not answer my question

Comment: Can you post an image with the expected result? Like you want to show 3 different of information on a 2D graph... how is that? yes, we can use color but as you can see `src_port` is 100 unique numbers... it isn't practical

Comment: I cannot have image. Like X axis is time stamp, Y axis is port and IP is common to both port and time.

Comment: @Anwarvic: I edited question. Please respond

Comment: Could you add the value of `dict_a` to the question? If you read this data from a file, please upload it to a cloud-service like GoogleDrive and provide the link