# How to plot certain data with different color in one plot in python?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a list of lists, and each list has three items. The first two are numbers, those are for the x and y axis. The third one is either True or False. I need to plot those numbers, which have True next to them with blue (which is the basic color for Python), and those with False value with red. How can I make the last one happen?

So far I plotted everything with blue, I do not know how to plot certain values with red.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Color by Column Values in Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14885895/color-by-column-values-in-matplotlib)

Comment: Or use seaborn - `seaborn.scatterplot(data=df, x='xcol', y='ycol', hue='TruFalseCol')`

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```py
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [
    [1, 2, True],
    [4, 5, False],
    [7, 9, True],
    [12, 13, True],
    [15, 3, False],
    [18, 4, False],
    [20, 11, True]
]

# convert to numpy array
npdata = np.asarray(data)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# get True indices
trueidx = np.argwhere(npdata[:,2] == True).squeeze()

# get False indices
falseidx = np.argwhere(npdata[:,2] == False).squeeze()

ax.plot(npdata[trueidx, 0], npdata[trueidx, 1], "b", label="True")
ax.plot(npdata[falseidx, 0], npdata[falseidx, 1], "r", label="False")
ax.legend()

fig.show()
```

This gives:

[image]

If you just want to plot the points as dot rather than joined with lines, change `"r"` to `"ro"` in the `plot` command, and similarly for `"b"` to `"bo"`.