# Color scatterplot by grouping in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Having a pandas `df` as follows:

```
# Sample data
data = {
    'x': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    'y': [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
    'z': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A']
}

# Creating a pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I try to make a scatterplot that colors each group individually.

I tried (following my intuition..):

```
df.groupby('z').plot.scatter('x', 'y', color = 'z')
```

This doesn't work..

---

So I searched and found:

```
plt.figure()
for z in df['z'].unique():
    subset = df[df['z'] == z]
    plt.scatter(subset['x'], subset['y'])
```

This works and produces:

[image].

But to me, this seems like a 'workaround'. Is there really no way to use the pandas grouping directly as an argument for the plotting method?

Comment: Can you provide a example dataset and ideally a schematic of the graph that you would expect?

Comment: @mozway Thx for your reply. I added a `df` and the expected output.

Comment: I see, you want the same plot (`groupby` is used to create multiple plots), then it's already well described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14885895/color-a-scatter-plot-by-column-values). You have options in pure pandas and with `seaborn` that is also a nice alternative for full customization ;)

Comment: `df.plot.scatter('x', 'y', c='z')` is the most straightforward if you have color codes

Comment: @mozway Thx. That is basically what I was searching for.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.plot.scatter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.scatter.html) with pass `color` with convert strings to numeric by [`Categorical`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html) and [`Categorical.codes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.codes.html), also is possible use custom [`colormap`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/colors/colormaps.html):

```
df.plot.scatter('x', 'y', color = pd.Categorical(df['z']).codes, cmap='viridis')
```