# Using Pyplot to plot a add a column of a data frame as a legend

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm loading the following data into a data frame using pandas and then pyplot to plot two columns on a scatter plot. I am looking to add a third column (LLOC_ID) as a key on the plot, using colours preferably. How would I go about doing this?

| LLOC_ID | ISPT_TOP | ISPT_MAIN |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BH02 | 1.5 | 40 |
| BH01 | 1 | 50 |
| BH01 | 1 | 10 |
| BH04 | 2.5 | 12 |

```
LOCA = AGS4.convert_to_numeric(tables['ISPT'])
df = pd.DataFrame(LOCA)
print(pd.DataFrame(LOCA))
#Check Geometry
print(df[["LOCA_ID","ISPT_TOP", "ISPT_MAIN"]])

df.plot.scatter(x='ISPT_MAIN', y='ISPT_TOP', style='o').invert_yaxis()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The df.plot.scatter()
you’re using is nice enough.
Certainly it is convenient.

But you’d be happier with “import seaborn as sns”, and then using sns.scatterplot().
If your data frame has sensible column names, then the labeling concerns you’re currently worrying about often get solved “for free”, by nicely defaulted options.

https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html

Comment: ... which makes this a [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14885895/color-a-scatter-plot-by-column-values). No need to post an answer.